# How do I disable faces on contacts?

Tags: contacts, sms

On an older version contacts without images are a solid color. Now its a solid color with a blank face drawn on top of it. It's irritating. How can I disable it? I also would like to disable the face/color box next in the text message conversation.

I'm using version 4.3

Comment: What device is this?

Comment: If it's rooted and you have a backup copy of the ROM, you could potentially replace the actual blank face image with something more visually pleasing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the stock `Contacts` and `Messaging` apps do not have the option to hide the profile pictures.

However, you can try [GO Contacts Ex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro&hl=en) and [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en). These are highly-customizable 3rd-party apps that allow you to hide profile pictures. I'm sure other apps can hide the pictures two, but those are are what I've tried so far, and it works well.